How to exclude SwiftUI files from Unit Test code coverage?
I search in google and found that if we add #preview in swiftui class then it will not consider for code coverage, but it still considered.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


Am I missed anything , please help to solve this issue .

Are you asking about excluding the #Preview lines from code coverage or SwiftUI files in their entirety?  I created a sample app and ran the default tests and got 100% coverage.

@Paulw11 I am asking about excluding the entire SwiftUI files. You are getting 100% code coverage because that ContentView is called in the root file. Please create a new SwiftUI file and don't call it anywhere. Then you will see 0% code coverage in that file. This will lead to reduced code coverage for the entire project.

Xcode doesn't support excluding a file from code coverage

@Paulw11 then how will we get exact code coverage by excluding views? please share your thoughts.

You can't with Xcode. You can look at external tools or you can include ui tests that invoke all views
